# filepicker urls with s3

Tags: amazon-s3, filepicker

I'm looking to build a photo management app and I've decided to use Filepicker.io with Amazon s3 to manage the uploads/hosting of static files. I plan on having Filepicker handle the upload of images to s3, and then I will store the url of the image in a database -- these urls will be embedded in a template. For example,

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="datafile">
  {{#if src}}
  <img src='{{src}}'>
  {{/if}}
```

Javascript :

```
'change input' : function (e, t) {

      var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
      if (file) {
        filepicker.store(file, function(fp){
          // Set URL to fpURL 
        }, function(err){
          console.log('error', err);
        }, function(progress){
          console.log('loading', progress);
        });
      }

    }
```

My question: Is it better to store the filepicker url in the database? Or should I be saving  the `key` url, which can link directly to s3?

My filePicker success object looks like this:

```
{url: "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/wppeyWAUQaaX0HPgXQ", 
size: 76511, type: "image/png", 
key: "EdqmSpbDQziIvSfI4g_logo.png", 
filename: "logo.png"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recommend storing the URL directly, as that way you can take advantage of the [conversion features](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#fpurl-images) and other functionality we provide on top of the URLs. Plus, you don't have to mess with the S3 APIs directly and can perform GETs and POSTs on the url instead

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing, and it seems to work well.

Comment: so will this continue to work if i leave filepicker.io? or once my account is deactivated my urls all break?

Comment: If you deactivate your account, we can work with you to ensure that you can transition off the service smoothly. We'd be sad to see you go though!