# InkFilePicker - Upload an already existing S3 File

Tags: filepicker.io

What I would like to accomplish without having to create a field in my users database table.

Let's say user uploads an image, and crops it. Now the final version of that image creates an inkBlob url, and it also stores it to my s3 account.

The user looks at his or her image and says, let me crop it again.

With out storing the final inkBlob url, is there a way to pull the last image from s3 and re-upload it to inkFilePicker so that I can take advantage of the conversion API functions?

I would really like to accomplish this with out having to save the final inkBlob url to my database as recommended in the following link;

[filepicker urls with s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315655/filepicker-urls-with-s3)